# how to save enum value to session

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, enums

I'm creating enum property. This property should saved into session. My code is here

`public enum TPageMode { Edit=1,View=2,Custom=3}`

```
       protected TPageMode Mode { 
            get{
                if (Session["Mode"] == null)
                    return TPageMode.Edit;
                else
                {
                    return Session["Mode"] as TPageMode; // This row is problem
                }                
            }
            set {
                Session["Mode"] = value;
            } 
        }
```

compiler release error on `return Session["Mode"] as TPageMode`

`The as operator must be used with a reference type or nullable type`

When i replacing this row to

```
return Enum.Parse(typeof(TPageMode), Session["Mode"].ToString());
```

This error shown

`Cannot implicit convert type 'object' to 'TPageMode'`

How to read Enum value from session?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
return (TPageMode) Session["Mode"];
```

As the error message says, "as" can't be used with non-nullable value types. Enum.Parse *would* have worked (inefficiently) if you'd then cast to the right type:

```
return (TPageMode) Enum.Parse(Session["Mode"], typeof(TPageMode));
```

Answer (score 1):

The code

```
return Session["Mode"] as TPageMode
```

returns an error, because `TPageMode` is not a reference type.

The `as` operator is a special kind of reflection-based type conversion in C#. It checks whether the left-hand-side of operator can be converted to the type on the right-hand-side. If the conversion is **not** possible, the expression returns null. Since `TPageMode` is an enum and is based on value types, it cannot hold the value null. As such, the operator cannot be used in this example.

To perform this type conversion, simply use

```
return (TPageMode) Session["Mode"];
```

Using this syntax, if the conversion is not possible, an `InvalidCastException` is thrown by the runtime. Use this syntax when you are confident the conversion should always be possible in normal circumstances.